# ПовторятьПриПечатиСтроки разная шапка

Tags: 1с

товарищи 1Сники, помогите, пожалуйста.

у меня при печати отчета надо выводить на каждом следующем листе шапку таблички. но проблема в том, что шапка у меня меня меняется. как по содержимому столбцов так и по их количеству. Поэтому ПовторятьПриПечатиСтроки использовать не получается. так как там задаётся жестко область откуда надо взять шапку и всё. а мне бы эту шапку брать с разных областей табличного документа. что можно было бы посоветовать ?

Comment: Какая конфигурация?

Comment: @Sagittarius
Управление производственным предприятием, редакция 1.3 (1.3.202.1)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно посмотреть, как сделан вывод шапки в какой-нибудь типовой форме. Там создается массив областей и при выводе проверяется, влазят они на лист или нет. В зависимости от этого определяется, нужно ли выводить шапку. Можно вывести что угодно: получаете нужную область и выводите.
Посмотрите в СП метод "ПроверитьВывод()" объекта "ТабличныйДокумент"

Comment: насколько я знаю проверитьВывод() области использует поименованные. а я таким образом области не использую. а вывожу при помощи  ТД.Область(х,у, х , у).Текст = Текст;

Comment: @АндрейГуренков, посмотрите описание в СП. Параметром может служить массив областей. Помещайте нужные области в массив и проверяйте. Вам надо посмотреть какую-нибудь типовую форму. Там такой подход используют.

Comment: описание чего мне посмотреть ??? я не могу типовую форму таблицы использовать. у меня в тд надо чтобы напечатлись таблицы с разным количеством столбцов и содержанием этих столбцов  - что-то вроде кросстаблиц . задачу ставлю не я. Вообще у меня получилось. Если интересно расскажу как.

Comment: @АндрейГуренков, описание метода. Я не говорил использовать типовую, а посмотреть как там сделано для образца. Получилось - хорошо, я знаю как это реализовать, но советую всегда писать найденное решение в сформированном вопросе. Возможно кто-то попадет сюда через поиск и ему это поможет.

Comment: ну я когда писал этот вопрос сюда не знал как реализовать. это сам в процессе нарыл пока мы тут общались.